# Gitlab: Send Email to clients with changes to a file of a directory

Tags: gitlab

We would like to notify the client (via Email e.g.)whenever a file of a certain directory changes with the said changes and preferably the entire file.

I did some research on this topic and I found some possible solutions, but none are really sufficient (as far as I can tell). Gitlab Integration "Emails on push" would be excellent, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to limit it to trigger it only for certain changes.

The other possibility would be to send an Email in the CI/CD Pipeline from Gitlab while defining a rule that it only runs the job, when a file in a certain directory has changed. While this solution sounds really great, I haven't found a way to also include the diffs of the changed files in said Email.

Does anyone have any experience implementing this specific use-case? I'd also be open to alternative solutions.